"He is not much good" — correct with "much". "She didn't look much disappointed" — is this correct with "much" too?
from an answer on ell.stackexchange.com:

If "much" qualifies a simple adverb or a simple adjective, you can use it in a negative sentence:
(1) He is not much good. — OK

The word "simple" makes the rule very bad and unclear because it's not understood what "simple" means.
Is the past participle adjective "disappointed" considered simple or not?
for example:
(2) She didn't look much disappointed.
Is (2) correct?
P.S.:  I know I can say (1) and (2) with "very":
(1a) He is not very good. — correct
(2a) She didn't look very disappointed. — correct

Also I wonder whether adding "very" to "much" would change the correctness of the sentences or not:
(1b) He is not very much good.
(2b) She didn't look very much disappointed.
Are (1b) and (2b) correct?


In the answer you have quoted from, simple is contrasted with comparative. The point they were making was, you can say much faster but not much fast. So your sentence (2) is wrong, but She didn't look much more disappointed [than she was yesterday] would be fine.

@PeterKirkpatrick Your use of "so" in the sentence "So your sentence (2) is wrong" doesn't make sense. "So" makes this sentence illogical in terms of what you wrote before.

It makes sense to me. Your sentence #2 is: She didn't look much disappointed. The link explains that in this context much is attached to the comparative adjective (more disappointed), not the simple adjective (disappointed). So (=therefore) your sentence is wrong. But my variation gives a possible correct usage.

Note that these are comments, not an answer. I was trying to help on the particular issue of simple and its meaning. The word much has a range of meanings and uses.

I would suggest that good in not much good is a noun, not an adjective - compare not much use.

@PeterKirkpatrick The question is not about comparatives. "Good" is not a comparative form! What you wrote does not answer what's the difference between "not much good" and "not much disappointed", why one of them is correct whereas the other is not. On the contrary, your comments prove that "not much good" is incorrect as well as "not much disappointed" is (because "good" is not a comparative as well as "disappointed") !!! That's why your "so" is illogical.

@KateBunting A link says the sentence "I'm not much good at knitting" is also correct. Is "good" a noun here too?

I think (I'm) not much good at is an idiom, with the sense (I) don't have much skill in.

@KateBunting Therefore, you mean that the rule — if "much" qualifies a simple adverb or a simple adjective, you can use it in a negative sentence — is wrong because "not much good" is just an exclusion, right?

@Loviii, you need to be careful and remember that we are volunteers trying to help you. I don't particularly like being shouted at with multiple exclamation marks. If you go back to your OP you will see that early in the question you say, It's not clear what simple means. (Quoting the link you provided.) I made it clear all along that I was responding to that point and nothing else, which is why I made a small comment, not a full answer. Go back and read my comments with that attitude and you will understand them better.

I think you mean 'an exception'? See Stuart's excellent answer. 'Not much' can also be used in a negative sentence with a noun (I mentioned 'not much use' in my first comment).

@PeterKirkpatrick Back to your first comment: from the beginning "In the answer you have quoted from, simple is contrasted with comparative. The point they were making was, you can say much faster but not much fast. So your sentence (2) is wrong,", we must also conclude that "not much good" is wrong too because "good" is not a comparative. But since "not much good" is correct, your comment is illogical and I was so shocked by this that I wrote the exclamation marks. Sorry for them.

It seems to me that the mistake you made was to assume that if I had an opinion on one sentence I must have exactly the same opinion on every other sentence. Is that a fair comment?

@PeterKirkpatrick I think it's not fair because you wrote the phrase "you can say much faster but not much fast" as the general idea. That is, it has to be considered as the rule applying not only to (2), but to every other similar sentence, including (1).

Well this latest comment proves my point. You are saying my example has to be considered as the rule applying not only to (2) but to every other similar sentence. Your words. But it's not my position. The answers show that the rules are more detailed and nuanced, and subject to exceptions. The joys of English. However, this will be my last comment on the subject.

@PeterKirkpatrick "However, this will be my last comment on the subject" - this is passive aggression. Ending up a conversation with phrases like this, you characterize yourself in a negative way. That's not good.

@PeterKirkpatrick "However, this will be my last comment on the subject" - by the way, don't lie. You yourself asked me the question "Is that a fair comment?". That is, that was you who asked me to continue the conversation. But your sentence "However, this will be my last comment on the subject" implies as if that were me who asked you a question at the end of the conversation which you're answering and after which you're saying that you will answer other questions no more. So that's a lie.


I need to hammer this nail. Why did you hand me a screwdriver? A screwdriver's not much good.

That is, a screwdriver is ill-suited for hammering.

When I told him there was no Santa Claus, he didn't look much disappointed. Perhaps one of his fellow students at the university had already told him?

Common in the 19th century and earlier, "much disappointed" is grammatical but has now been ousted by very, at least in American English.  Until around the middle of the 20th century, authors on "correct" use of the language were insisting that much be used with participial adjectives.

The house was much dilapidated. obsolescent

much can be synonymous with "a lot" or "often" or "a good deal":

Do you run much?
Do you ski much?
You're gasping for breath after a few jumping jacks. Exercise much?

But the answer cannot use much in the affirmative:

Yes, I run much.  ungrammatical
No, I don't exercise much. grammatical


If "He is not much good" is correct, then "He is not very much good" is correct too, right?

@Lovii I've never heard anyone ever say He is not very much good.  I wouldn't consider it grammatical.

"not much good" is a special case. Generally "not much" is followed by a comparative adjective, e.g. "not much stupider/better/taller", a mass noun e.g. "not much sugar", or a countable noun with "of", e.g. "not much of a man".
There are other similar constructions like "not much use", "not much help", "not much point", where "use", "help", and "point" are nouns. So it might be assumed that "good" is a noun here, which it can be (Merriam-Webster), not an adjective.
So the rule would be

"Not much good" is fine.

"Not much" + comparative is fine.

"Not much" + mass noun is fine.

"Not much"+simple (non-comparative) adjective is not idiomatic.



If "He is not much good" is fine, then "He is not very much good" is fine too, right?
